# Command which only shows installed Games in my Android app?

Tags: android

I have heard about `getInstalledApplication()` but it shows all apps.

Is there a way to retrieve only apps that have been classified as games?

Thank you, any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It would be more helpful if you tried something and then indicate what problems you are encountering. Perhaps a good start is to look at [this example](http://techblogon.com/get-installed-applications-list-android-example/).

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry, there is no such function provided that classifies the apps like that.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that there isn't a simple easy one line of code to do this.

You can filter by checking for which features, services, or intents are used/implemented by the apps via the `PackageManager`, but there is no "I'm a game" flag you can filter by.

The Google Play store does have categories, but unless you want to go through and cross-check every installed app with calls to the Google Play API (which the apps may or may not be sourced from and therefore you can't confirm it is or is not a game) then you probably won't have a very clean way of doing this.